# no response from page when trying to insert data in table in sql server using asp.net and c# . data didn't insert sql server table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

no response from page when trying to insert data into table no data is inserted into table.I cant find error in code.no error showing in page.can anyone solve this error. thanks in advance. this is my first question i am asking in satackoverflow.

```
 protected void addbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String constr = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbconnection"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);

            try
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("insert into emp_table2(firstName, lastName, age, pos, date) values(@firstName, @lastName, @age, @pos, date)", con);

                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstName", txtfname.Text);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastName", txtlname.Text);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@age", txtage.Text);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pos", postxt.Text);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", date.Text);
                com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
                Response.Write("<script>alert('Employee added successfully.')</script>");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
```

```
<div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
            <table class="table">
               
                <tr>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <td><asp:TextBox class="form-control" ID="txtfname" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox class="form-control" ID="txtlname" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>age</th>
                    <td><asp:TextBox class="form-control" ID="txtage" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>position</th>
                    <td><asp:TextBox class="form-control" ID="postxt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Start-date</th>
                    <td><asp:TextBox class="form-control" ID="date" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Button class="btn btn-success" ID="addbtn" runat="server" Text="Add" OnClick="addbtn_Click"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Button class="btn btn-danger" ID="cancbtn" runat="server" Text="Cancel" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
```

i want to insert data in table in `sql server` using a `boostrap` page in asp.net and backend coding done on `c#`.

Comment: Get an error message from somewhere... The SQL Server logs, the browsers, console, etc.

Comment: how to get error message i have done this catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); nothing is coming
            }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is with the `date` column in the SQL insert statement. You are not properly specifying the parameter for the date value. You need to use the parameter for the `@date` value, but you forgot the "@" symbol before "date" in your query
You have mention like:

```
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("insert into emp_table2(firstName, lastName, age, pos, date) values(@firstName, @lastName, @age, @pos, date)", con);
```

But it should be like this:

```
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("insert into emp_table2(firstName, lastName, age, pos, date) values(@firstName, @lastName, @age, @pos, @date)", con);
```

For optimal resource management, contemplate implementing the using statement with `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` instances. This guarantees meticulous resource disposal, even in the event of an exception.

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
{
    con.Open();
    using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("insert into emp_table2(firstName, lastName, age, pos, date) values(@firstName, @lastName, @age, @pos, @date)", con))
    {
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstName", txtfname.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastName", txtlname.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@age", txtage.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pos", postxt.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", date.Text);
        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    Response.Write("<script>alert('Employee added successfully.')</script>");
}
```

Comment: after correcting date this error comes in console of web browser:- Uncaught (in promise) Error: A listener indicated an asynchronous response by returning true, but the message channel closed before a response was received

Comment: corrected this error but no error nothing happening in page

Comment: sql server column name not matching with sql command column name so i corrected then it run fine